# Xubuntu, XFCE Customization

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, xfce, menu, panel

I've very recently installed Xubuntu and I wanted to inquire about a few things regarding customization:

How do I get a panel I've created to stick be behind active windows at all times? Basically turn a panel into a widget, I know how to create a panel but they are always above windows.

How do I customize the "whisker menu"? I understand how to customize the icon or title but how do I change the style/color of the menu itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up the hidden file named .gtkrc-2.0 in your home directory with any text editor you want.

If the file doesn’t exist, create it.

If you want to change the background color of the menu window add something like this:

```
style "darkback"
{
    bg[NORMAL] = "#404040"
    bg[ACTIVE] = "#606060"
    bg[PRELIGHT] = "#808080"
}
widget "whiskermenu-window*" style "darkback"
```

[image]

If you want to change the window text color as well, add something like this:

```
style "darkback"
{
    bg[NORMAL] = "#404040"
    bg[ACTIVE] = "#606060"
    bg[PRELIGHT] = "#808080"
    fg[NORMAL] = "#ccc"
    fg[ACTIVE] = "#fff"
    fg[PRELIGHT] = "#fff"
}
widget "whiskermenu-window*" style "darkback"
```

[image]

If you want to change the background color of the menu items, add something like this:

```
style "darktree"
{
    base[NORMAL] = "#404040"
    base[ACTIVE] = "#606060"
}
widget "whiskermenu-window*TreeView*" style "darktree"
```

[image]

If you want to change the text color of the menu items as well, add something like this:

```
style "darktree"
{
    base[NORMAL] = "#404040"
    base[ACTIVE] = "#606060"
    text[NORMAL] = "#ccc"
    text[ACTIVE] = "#fff"
}
widget "whiskermenu-window*TreeView*" style "darktree"
```

[image]

Source: https://gottcode.wordpress.com/2013/

Answer (score 0):

If you have Xubuntu 15.04 ([xfce 4.12](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/03/install-xfce-412-in-xubuntu-1404-or.html)) you can make panel to be inteligent hided